# How to convert standard normal output to predictions?

Tags: statistics, linear-transformations, normal-distribution

I am using a linear model to perform predictions. My loss function is minimizing three seperate objective functions. In order to perform regression, I converted my 3 objective outputs to standard normal as

$y_1 = \frac{y_1 - mean(y_1)}{std(y_1)}$

$y_2 = \frac{y_2 - mean(y_2)}{std(y_2)}$

$y_3 = \frac{y_3 - mean(y_3)}{std(y_3)}$

After obtaining model parameters, my prediction is also normally distributed. The prediction $ y^p = w^TX $, where $w$ is obtained through regression on the above $y$ values. In order to implement it in my system, I need the absolute prediction value for which I used the following relations

$y^{p}_1 = y^{p}_1*std(y_1) + mean(y_1)$

$y^{p}_2 = y^{p}_2*std(y_2) + mean(y_2)$

$y^{p}_3 = y^{p}_3*std(y_3) + mean(y_3)$

Its not giving me right values. Can you please help me on how can I resolve this issue?

Update: The regression model that I am using is relevance vector machines to get sparse parameters.